# continuous function from $[\pi,2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$f:I=[\pi,2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$

which of the following are necessarily correct?

$1$. $\exists t_0\in I$ such that $f'(t_0)=\frac{1}{\pi}(f(2\pi)-f(\pi))$

$2$. $\nexists t_0\in I$ such that $f'(t_0)=\frac{1}{\pi}(f(2\pi)-f(\pi))$

$3$.$\exists t_0\in I$ such that $\pi||f'(t_0)||\ge ||(f(2\pi)-f(\pi)||$

$4$. $f'(t)=(-\sin t,\cos t)\forall t$

$4$ is clearly true, $1$ is true by Mean Value Theorem as $f$  satisfies all the conditions of MVT? have no idea of $2$ and $3$, Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 is true.

1 does **not follow from the MVT** because $f$ is a function into the plane not the line of reals. The MVT applies to each coordinate separately, giving $t_1,t_2$ which are in general distinct. Try to find a point $t_0$ by considering the second coordinate and then the first?

2 is just the opposite of 1.

3 follows from the triangle inequality - if the derivative were any smaller than this everywhere, the curve soul wouldn't be long enough to join its endpoints!

Comment: could you tell me whether and how $1$ is true or false?, $1,3,4$ are true?

Comment: RHS is $1/\pi(2,0)$, the left hand side is $(-\sin t_0,\cos t_0)$ - can these ever be equal?

Answer (score 0):

$(1)\Leftrightarrow (\sim(2))$ and $(1)\Rightarrow (3)$, isn't it?